# Add a firewall rule for Distributed Transaction Coordinator (msdtc.exe)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I tried to use `firewallAPI.dll` to add a rule. It works fine for calc.exe (or some other files) as described bellow but fails for `msdtc.exe` with the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var manager = GetFirewallManager();
    if (manager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe";
        //var path = @"C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe"; // System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file specified.
        AuthorizeApplication("Test", path, NET_FW_SCOPE_.NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL, NET_FW_IP_VERSION_.NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY);
    }
}

private const string CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER =
    "{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}";

private static NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr GetFirewallManager()
{
    Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(
        new Guid(CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER));
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType)
        as NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr;
}

private const string PROGID_AUTHORIZED_APPLICATION =
    "HNetCfg.FwAuthorizedApplication";
public static bool AuthorizeApplication(string title, string applicationPath,
    NET_FW_SCOPE_ scope, NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ ipVersion)
{
    // Create the type from prog id
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(PROGID_AUTHORIZED_APPLICATION);
    INetFwAuthorizedApplication auth = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
        as INetFwAuthorizedApplication;
    auth.Name = title;
    auth.ProcessImageFileName = applicationPath;
    auth.Scope = scope;
    auth.IpVersion = ipVersion;
    auth.Enabled = true;

    INetFwMgr manager = GetFirewallManager();
    manager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications.Add(auth);
    return true;
}
```

Note: I checked the folder and see the file is located properly...
Could anybody help to add firewall rule for **Distributed Transaction Coordinator**? Maybe I should try to add another file to firewall (not msdtc.exe)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it, there is no 32-bit version of msdtc.exe.

Why the file system redirector caused the FileNotFoundException is explained well in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).